# running shell script on low privileged user

Tags: linux, shell

I have a requirement to run a java jar on a low privilege user on linux.

e.g. If I am currently logged in as a 'root' user and want to execute a shell script that should run with the privileges of a low privileged linux user like 'postix' user account.

Is it possible?

If yes, please post relevant references as I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Ashish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) command to run the script as another user.
If its set up properly, you can use it like this

```
sudo -u andrew myprog
```

will run myprog as the user andrew

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by priority. If you think about scheduling priority, you can use the `nice` command to run the script with low priority on the CPU. Being logged as 'root' does not give any scheduling priority.

*Besides this, it is always a bad idea to be logged in as 'root'.*

Comment: with the privileges of low priority linux  if i understood correctly, "privileges" is more important then "priority" in this sentence.

Comment: my mistake, I meant 'low privilege' instead of 'low priority'

Answer (score 2):

I think sudo should do the trick .

You can also create script that will run your app change its owner and set suid bit for it

useful commands: chmode, chown